# How to implement semantic search using Azure Cognitive Search Javascript Integration (@azure/search-documents npm package)

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-cognitive-search

I'm building a nextjs app which responds to questions pulled from a CSV, there is a call to cognitive search which retrieves relevant documents, I then pass this to the OpenAI service.

There is very little documentation available on how to integrate azure's semantic search feature in javascript. I am using the [@azure/search-documents](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/search-documents) library to make the calls.

You should be able to put "semantic" as a value for the queryType property in the search configuration, however it's not included as a valid type in this package. I'm wondering if anyone else has ever implemented semantic search using this package.

Here is the code so far for making the request and handling the search results:

```
import { IError } from "@/app/_lib/ts/types/error";
import { AzureKeyCredential, SearchClient } from "@azure/search-documents";
import { QueryType, SearchMode } from "azure-search-types";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

// Define a TypeScript interface for the fields to extract from the search query
export interface AzureCognitiveSearchResult {
  score: number;
  document: any; // Adjust the type of "document" based on your actual document structure
}

// Search config
const searchConfig = {
  top: 2,
  searchMode: SearchMode.any,
  queryType: QueryType.simple,
};

// Default minimum score for which to return results
const defaultMinScore = '14.0';

export interface AzureCognitiveSearchResponse {
  query: {
    _id: string,
    input: string,
    results: AzureCognitiveSearchResult[]
  }
} 

export async function POST(req: NextRequest): Promise<NextResponse> {
  let searchResults: AzureCognitiveSearchResponse[] = [];
  const serviceName = process.env.AZURE_COGNITIVE_SEARCH_SERVICENAME;
  const indexName = process.env.AZURE_COGNITIVE_SEARCH_INDEXNAME;
  const adminKey = process.env.AZURE_COGNITIVE_SEARCH_QUERYKEY;
  const endpoint = `https://${serviceName}.search.windows.net/indexes/${indexName}/docs/search?api-version=2023-11-01`;

  const { data, minScore } = await req.json();

  if (!data) {
    return NextResponse.json({ message: "No data passed to the Cognitive Search API" }, { status: 400 });
  }

  try {
    // To query and manipulate documents
    const searchClient = new SearchClient(
      endpoint,
      indexName,
      new AzureKeyCredential(adminKey),
    );

    for (const queryGroup of data) {
      const queryResultGroup = await searchClient.search(queryGroup.query, searchConfig);

      const obj: AzureCognitiveSearchResponse = {
        query: {
          _id: queryGroup._id,
          input: queryGroup.query,
          results: []
        }
      };

      for await (const result of queryResultGroup.results) {
        if (result.score >= parseFloat(minScore || defaultMinScore)) {
          const resultObj: AzureCognitiveSearchResult = {
            score: result.score,
            document: result.document,
          };

          obj.query.results.push(resultObj);
        }
      }

      searchResults.push(obj);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return NextResponse.json({ message: "An error occurred fetching data from the Cognitive Search API" }, { status: 500 });
  }

  return NextResponse.json({ searchResults }, { status: 200 });
}
```

Comment: are you using the latest npm version 12.0.0?

Comment: here is an example in javascript: https://github.com/Azure/azure-search-vector-samples/blob/4210bf69e6385285ec5f99a8e605f3c88cb61a1b/demo-javascript/JavaScriptVectorDemo/code/azure-search-vector-sample.js#L315

Comment: @Farzzy-MSFT I'm using NPM 9.8.1. Thanks for the link I replicated the code for semantic search and I'm receiving the following error in the console: Error "semantic is not a valid value for searchRequest.queryType. The valid values are: ["simple","full"]." occurred in serializing the payload - undefined.

Answer (score 1):

I had to update `@azure/search-documents` to the latest version (12.0.0) and my problem was fixed